# Context or Namespace for objects in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a query, of very many lines, that I want to run in different MySQL and SQL Server databases. I want to avoid editing the `From` clause each time e.g. from `[db1].[dbo].[Mytable]` to `[db2].[dbo].[Mytable]` to `db3.MyTable` etc.

Is there a portable SQL way to define the context, sort of like a "namespace" in programming. As in:

```
using context [db1].[dbo] //modify for each separate databases,environments
//rest of query
```

Comment: Do you run these queries manually? If not, your environment might have the tools to manipulate them for you

Comment: Yes, I have to, to debug what's going on. I paste my queries in MySQL Query Browser and SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Have you thought about writing a microscopic [PHP|C#|Whatever] program to take a query template (e.g. having $$CONTEXT$$ for [db1].[dbo]), filling it in and running it via ODBC or friends? 3 Arguments: Query template file, ODBC Datasource name, Context

Comment: Please disregard my former comment: While I was writing it, you edited your comment to include the debugging requirement.... bad timing

Comment: Do all your queries run on the same database in a given instance?  Or does each instance also have multiple databases (hence the need to specify the full name).  If no - look into the USE statement for both MSSQL and MySql.

Comment: Thanks @RThomas. use <database_name>; //rest of query. was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Good . I added my comment as an answer with links to the docs for each db so you can close out the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as all your queries run on the same database in a given instance.  Look into the USE statement for both MSSQL and MySql.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188366.aspx